# How to get rid of any while passing an array of objects with certain requirements on the keys?

Tags: typescript

Given the example below, how to leverage `typescript`'s strong typing to ensure that the `data` parameter passed to the constructor of the class `Table` meets the following requirements :

1. it is an array
2. of objects of the same type
3. which contains at least all the different fields passed in the parameter `columnInfo`

```
interface ColumnInfo {
    name: string,
    displayed: boolean
}

class Table {
    constructor(columnInfo: ColumnInfo[], data: any[]) {
        //do something with columnInfo and data
    }
}

const columns: ColumnInfo[] = [
    { name: "id", displayed: true },
    { name: "age", displayed: true },
];

const data = [
    { id: 1, age: 56 },
    { id: 2, age: 112 },
    { id: 3, age: 33 },
]

const badData = [
    { id: 1, name: "john" },
    { id: 2, name: "marie" },
    { id: 3, name: "james" },
]

const demo1 = new Table(columns, data); //must work
const demo2 = new Table(columns, badData); //must fail because column "age" is missing from 'badData'
```

To be more accurate: I would like to have an error at transpile time, not runtime

Answer (score 0):

Solution : use Generics.

```
interface UserDataType {
    id: number,
    age: number
}

interface ColumnInfo<DataType> {
    name: string,
    displayed: boolean
}

class Table<T> {
    constructor(columnInfo: ColumnInfo<T>[], data: T[]) {
        //do something with columnInfo and data
    }
}

const columns: ColumnInfo<UserDataType>[] = [
    { name: "id", displayed: true },
    { name: "age", displayed: true },
];

const data: UserDataType[] = [
    { id: 1, age: 56 },
    { id: 2, age: 112 },
    { id: 3, age: 33 },
]

const badData = [
    { id: 1, name: "john" },
    { id: 2, name: "marie" },
    { id: 3, name: "james" },
]

const demo1 = new Table(columns, data); //must work
const demo2 = new Table(columns, badData); //must fail because column "age" is missing from 'badData'
```